# How to create a public webserver api documentation with doxygen?

Tags: php, api, webserver, documentation, doxygen

I would like to build an `webserver api` with `php` and want to generate a public documentation for the `api endpoints` using `doxygen`.

So far I know how to get doxygen going for my internal code-documentation, but I would like to create a second public documentation which is only describing the public webserver endpoints.

I would like to place the corresponding documentation into my controllers and actions so that any end-point-changes can be updated at the same time when developing instead of having to maintain code and documentation in parallel.
So in gerenal I'd need a way to mark my public documentations somehow and make doxygen whitelist those only for my public documentation.

Is there a standard or best-practice way to achieve this?
What are necessary configuration steps?
are there any doxygen-based tools that can help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself. The correct way to do this is to use "OpenAPI"-tools that are often compatible with the swagger syntax in all common programming languages. (some frameworks even provide build-in support e.g. LoopBack)
OpenAPI-specifications are designed to create a documentation for externals only describing the public interfaces/API-endpoints

Answer (score 0):

Some starting points:

- You need a second doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) with the relevant settings for the both cases
- you probably need to do something with commands like `\if`, `\ifnot` `\else`, `\endif`, `\cond` and `\endcond` as well as the `ENABLED_SECTIONS`, see the documentation.
- depending on the names of the functions etc. it might be possible to use `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS`
- depending on the way everything is setup it might be possible to reduce the external set of files.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
yes, so far i got a second configuration file going, but I do not think that wrapping all my documents block with \if and \endif is a doable solution.
is there a way to do it the other way around like "do not include any comments except of those with section/tag/annotation XYZ"?

Comment: Excluding all comments is not possible other than maybe wrapping every file in an `\cond` block and terminate this at places you want to have in the external documentation.